Duplicate message type name in different namespaces throws "already defined in file..." error
Assume the following proto files
File 1
syntax = "proto3";

package helloworld;

option csharp_namespace = "MyNamespace";
option java_package = "com.mynamespace";

message MyMessage {
    string title = 1;
}

File 2
syntax = "proto3";

package helloworld;

option csharp_namespace = "MyOtherNamespace";
option java_package = "com.myothernamespace";

message MyMessage {
    string title = 1;
}

When executing the following (on libprotoc 28.2):
protoc --csharp_out=./foo *
I get this error
foo.proto:9:16: "helloworld.MyMessage.title" is already defined in file "bar.proto".
foo.proto:8:9: "helloworld.MyMessage" is already defined in file "bar.proto".

When I transpile the exact same proto files to C# as part of my dotnet build (using Grpc.Tools,
Google.Protobuf) no such error occurs and the corresponding C# files get auto-generated successfully.
Is there any way I can avoid/work-around the error produced by protoc without modifying the proto files themselves?

Try running protoc twice, separately for each file. So that it never sees them both at the same time.
